# Why is my SharedPreferences not working?- The retrieved Object is null

Tags: java, android, json, gson, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save an object of `ColorBean` class, when app goes `onStop()`

```
public class MainActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

    private ColorAdapter expListAdapter;
        LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<ColorBean>> colorsMap2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<ColorBean>>();
        SharedPreferences prefs;
        static String fileName = "SharedObject";

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            ArrayList<String> groupNames = new ArrayList<String>();

            prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            final LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<ColorBean>> colorsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<ColorBean>>();

            ArrayList<ColorBean> color = new ArrayList<ColorBean>();
            //Trying to fetch the prefs
            colorsMap2 = (LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<ColorBean>>) loadFromSharedPrefs();

            if (colorsMap2 == null || colorsMap2.size() == 0)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Not Retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            //fetching them here too
            if (loadFromSharedPrefs() != null) {
                colorsMap2 = (LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<ColorBean>>) loadFromSharedPrefs();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            //saving the preferences
            saveToSharedPrefs(colorsMap2);
        }

        public void saveToSharedPrefs(Object objToSave) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(objToSave);
            editor.putString("MyObject", json);
            editor.commit();
        }

        public Object loadFromSharedPrefs() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Object obj = null;
            if (prefs != null) {
                String json = prefs.getString("MyObject", "");
                obj = gson.fromJson(json, Object.class);
            }
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain, completely and precisely, what "not working" means here.

Comment: whenever I kill and re-launch the app, the obj = gson.fromJson(json, Object.class);
returns null.

Comment: Check that prefs != null?

Comment: For the first time when the app is launched, This could give a null pointer exception:
String json = prefs.getString("MyObject", "");

Comment: I tried with 
Type mapType = new TypeToken<LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<ColorBean>>>(){}.getType();
But it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to change the line:

```
obj = gson.fromJson(json, Object.class);
```

to:

```
obj = gson.fromJson(json, LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<ColorBean>>.class);
```

**UPDATED**

Sorry, it's been a while since I used Gson, and yes you're right, what I said above won't work. You need to store the generic type information when you serialize the type, so you need to use Gson's `TypeToken` class when you serialize and deserialize:

```
Type mapType = new TypeToken<LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<ColorBean>>>(){}.getType();
```

Then serialize using:

```
String json = gson.toJson(objToSave, mapType);
```

and deserialize using:

```
obj = gson.fromJson(json, mapType);
```

There's a tutorial [here](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-serializing-classes-with-generic-type.jsp) covering using Gson with generic types.

Comment: Gives a compilation error:
Cannot Select from parameterized type.

Comment: Updated in response to comments.

Comment: @HexAndBugs what is that "Type"?

Comment: @HexAndBugs what class needs to be imported for the "Type"?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to do it from memory, and my memory's clearly not that good :(  I've updated the code above and added a link to a tutorial. `Type` is `java.lang.reflect.Type`

Comment: I made the Object obj a reference variable and it works as expected now.